# Difference between "their dependencies" and "their respective dependencies"

Tags: word-choice

This came up when I'm writing deployment instructions for virtual machine operating system software packages.

Suppose the goal is to install php, perl, and python along with any dependencies required, using the default package manager of the system, what's the difference (however subtle) with writing "their dependencies" and "their respective dependencies" in the instruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Their dependencies" would be the dependencies for all three, whereas "their respective dependencies" would be the dependencies for each one. So:
"Install A, B and C. Their dependencies are X, Y and Z."
or
"Install A, B and C. Their respective dependencies are X and Y (for A), X and Z (for B), and X, Y and Z (for C)."